# Why URL is changing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a simple servlet like this:

```
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final String userID = "root";
    private final String password = "root";

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.html");
            rd.include(request, response);
    }
}
```

Also I have login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user">
    <br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In browser I start my app http://localhost:8080/LoginCookie/ and browser shows login.html. Then I click "Login" button and URL is changing to http://localhost:8080/LoginCookie/LoginServlet.

How do I disable it?

Comment: I think this is just because the LoginServlet is executed and as the url is just a path to the server I'd say it's not possible to avoid the url from changing... Why does it bother you anyway?

Comment: If I type http://localhost:8080/LoginCookie/LoginServlet browser shows error  HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Comment: @xskit Of course because you do not have a doGet method in your Servlet...

Comment: Really, I am stupid :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *including* your HTML, you could instead *redirect* to your `login.html`

Consider using

```
response.sendRedirect("login.html");
```

instead of `rd.include()`

Redirecting has the nice side-effect that reloading the page will reload login.html instead of triggering your servlet again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay on the same page, leave the `action` attribute empty into your `form` tag

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

But then, you have to make sure that your `Servlet` will receive your `form`. `LoginServlet` will not receive the form request anymore, it will be sent to Servlet mappend with the URL of your current position. So you'll have to make a Servlet receiving this info.

Comment: Servlet was mapped to /LoginServlet - so removing that action will break the code.

Comment: @Jan That is the reason why I added that he had to prepare for this change by modifying his servlet. The mapping can be changed. I'm editing the psot.